# How to set position of checkbox to middle of td and input type text using css?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

How to set position of checkbox to middle of td and input type text using css ?

http://jsfiddle.net/3d6f2od6/1/

i tried to set position middle for checkbox buy not work , how can i do that ?

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#f7f8f9" style=" background: none; ">
    <tbody>
        <tr style=" display: block; ">                 
            <td valign="top" style=" border: 1px solid; ">
                <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="555"/>
                <input type="text" value=""/>  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `vertical-align: middle` to the `input` elements.

```css
input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#f7f8f9" style=" background: none; ">
  <tbody>
    <tr style=" display: block; ">
      <td style="border: 1px solid; ">
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="555" />
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```